# Domain over which differential equations are defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through Exercise 6 in Tenenbaum and I keep having various problems getting the correct answer.
On problem 2 I have the following issue:

$$xdy-ydx=0$$
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{y}dy-\frac{1}{x}dx=0, \text{ provided } x \neq 0, y \neq 0\end{equation}
Now integrating:
\begin{equation} \int \frac{1}{y}dy- \int \frac{1}{x}dx=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \log \lvert y \rvert-\log \lvert x\rvert=C \end{equation}

Adding $\log \lvert x \rvert$ to both sides gives us

\begin{equation} \log \lvert y \rvert =\log \lvert x \rvert +C \end{equation}
Now we take the exponential of both sides of the equation:
\begin{equation} e^{\log \lvert y \rvert}=e^{ \log\lvert x \rvert+C} \end{equation}
By the laws of logarithms and exponents this becomes
\begin{equation} \lvert y \rvert=A \lvert x \rvert \end{equation}
If $x \neq 0$, then we can choose two parameters $A_{1}$ and $A_2$ so that:

\begin{equation} y=A_{1}x \text{ for } x<0 \end{equation}

and \begin{equation} y=A_{2}x \text{ for } x>0 \end{equation}

But the answer given in the text is just $y=cx$, so I'm confused why the absolute value signs disappear and why $x=0$ is included in the domain. I also thought that $y=0$ was a particular solution that had to be excluded from the answer until I realized that it can be obtained by setting $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ equal to zero.

On problem 7 I have a similar issue:
\begin{equation}(y^2-1)dx-(2y+xy)dy=0 \end{equation}

\begin{equation} (y^2-1)dx-(2+x)ydy=0 \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{1}{x+2}dx-\frac{y}{y^2-1}dy=0 \end{equation}

Now integrating:

\begin{equation} \int \frac{1}{x+2}dx-\int \frac{y}{y^2-1}dy=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \log \lvert x+2 \rvert-\frac{1}{2}\log \lvert y^2-1 \rvert=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{1}{2}\log \lvert y^2-1 \rvert=\log \lvert x+2 \rvert+C \end{equation}

Now taking each side as an exponent:

\begin{equation} e^{ \frac{1}{2}\log \lvert y^2-1 \rvert}=e^{\log \lvert x+2 \rvert+C} \end{equation}

Again, I'm not entirely sure what can justify removing the absolute value signs, but the next step seems to be:

\begin{equation} \sqrt{y^2-1}=c(x+2) \end{equation}

\begin{equation} y^2=c(x+2)^2+1, x \neq -2, y\neq \pm1 \end{equation}

On problem 8 I encounter the following issue:

\begin{equation}x \log x dy+\sqrt{1+y^2}dx=0 \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy+\frac{1}{x\log x}dx=0, \text{ provided } x \neq 0, x \neq 1 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy+\int \frac{1}{x\log x}dx=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \int \frac{ \sec^{2}\left(\theta\right)}{ \sqrt{1+\tan^{2}\left(\theta\right)}} d \theta+ \int \frac{1}{x \log x}dx=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \int \sec \theta d \theta+ \int \frac{1}{ x \log x}dx=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \log \lvert \sec \theta +\tan \theta \rvert+ \log \lvert \log x \rvert=C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \log \lvert \sqrt{1+y^2}+ y \rvert+ \log \lvert \log x \rvert = C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} e^{ \log \lvert \sqrt{1+y^2}+y \rvert+ \log \lvert \log x \rvert }=e^C \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \lvert \sqrt{1+y^2}+y \rvert \log x=c, x \neq 0, x \neq 1 \end{equation}

However the answer provided in the text is

\begin{equation} log \vert x \rvert ( y+\sqrt{y^2+1})=c, x \neq 0, x \neq 1 \end{equation}

Again I'm not sure why it becomes $ \log \lvert x \rvert$ instead of $ \lvert \log x \rvert$

Another issue I encountered quite a bit was which points to exclude from the domain. If I need to divide by something to separate the variables, I must make sure that the denominator is not equal to zero. But if the solution doesn't contain any undefined points do I still need to exclude that point from its domain of definition? What if one were to find the solution a different way? The Exercises said to specify the common interval over which the differential equation and its solution are valid. The author sometimes seems to define the solution to differential equations so that removable discontinuities are "patched up" and I don't understand the justification for this.

Comment: Your critical points are valid. You would have to check back what your solution definition is for exact differential equations. The referenced solutions are compatible with differentiable curves whose tangents are in the direction field, in the kernel of the differential form. In the singular points like $(0,0)$ for the first example, the  kernel is the full space. (Note that also the curve $x=0$ is a solution.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what the differential forms are. If the kernels of the differential forms are the tangents. This level of abstraction is new to me. I understand that the differentials are linear functions tangent to the integral curves. Differential forms are some sort of generalization of the differentials? Because I don't see how you can define dy in terms of dx for the vertical line x=0.

Comment: In this context $dx,dy$ are not infinitesimals, but linear functions. For a vector $(u,v)$ you get $dx((u,v))=u$ and $dy((u,v))=v$. So for the integral curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(0,t)$ you get $dx(\dot\gamma(t))=0$ and $dy(\dot\gamma(t))=1$.

Comment: Why are the vectors in the direction field in the kernel in general though?

Comment: Because you want that the solutions or integral curves are defined to be tangent to the direction field. Or, the direction field is the kernel, the direction in a point is the kernel of the functional in that point.